# Demonstrate that $f^{-1}(w) =\frac {1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_\gamma \frac {zf^{\prime}(z)dz}{f(z)-w}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f: U \rightarrow \Bbb C$ be a univalent analytic function, and let $\gamma$ be a Jordan contour in $U$ with the property that the inside $D$ of the Jordan curve $ |\gamma |$ is contained in $U$. Demonstrate that for every point $w$ of the domain $D^ {\prime}=f(D)$ the value of the inverse of $f$ at $w$ is given by the formula

$$f^{-1}(w) =\frac {1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_\gamma \frac {zf^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)-w}\,dz$$

**My work:** 
Fix $w \in f(D)$ and let $f(a)=w, a \in D$. By the definition of univalent analytic function, let $h(z) =f(z)-f(a)=f(z)-w$ 
$$g(z)=\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-w}.$$
The only singularity of $g$ is at $a=f^{-1}(w)$, and it's a simple pole.
The residue there is
$$\lim_{z\to a}\left(zf'(z)\frac{z-a}{f(z)-f(a)}\right).$$ i.e The residue of $\operatorname{Res}\left(a, \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)-w}\right)=a$. Thus by residue theorem, $$ \int\limits_\gamma \frac {zf^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)-w}\,dz=2 \pi i (a)$$  Since $f^{-\prime} (w)=f^{-\prime} (f(a))=a$, we obtain 
$$f^{-1}(w) =a=\frac {1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_\gamma \frac {zf^{\prime}(z)}{f(z)-w}\,dz$$

Did I miss anything?  I appreciate your kind help. Thank you!

Comment: I think you mean $a$ instead of $z_0$ in the "My work" line, but other than that it looks good to me.

Comment: I have updated!

Comment: +1, looks good indeed!